# When does applicationDidBecomeActive get called with respect to requestAccessToEntityType?

Tags: ios, calendar, eventkit, ekeventstore

I just ran into an issue that I thought I'd share. In my iOS calendar usage, I'm making use of applicationDidBecomeActive in the app delegate to check if the users calendar settings have changed.  Specifically, after getting the applicationDidBecomeActive callback, I do the following:

```
// self.eventStore is of type EKEventStore *
EKCalendar *cal = [self.eventStore calendarWithIdentifier: calendarIdentifier];
if (!cal) {
    // Assume we no longer have access to the users calendar; e.g., they have change their privacy settings.
}
```

However, I ran into an issue. (How surprising! :)). I found that applicationDidBecomeActive is also called when we do initially do requestAccessToEntityType. That is, after Apple displays their "Alert" to the user to ask if the user wants our app to have access to their calendar, our app gets a applicationDidBecomeActive callback. My only remaining question with this, now that I've figured that out is:

When requestAccessToEntityType is called, do we always get the applicationDidBecomeActive *before* the completion handler of requestAccessToEntityType is called?

I'm assuming this is true. It would seem very unusual to me if one my methods was called (outside of the app delegate) before the app delegate applicationDidBecomeActive method was called.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is incorrect. The `requestAccessToEntityType:` callback can be executed *before* the app delegate `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method is called. I just observed this in my code. I'm not 100% sure if this is always the ordering of execution.

After thinking about this more, I'm now going to code so that I don't depend on this ordering of calls or on whether or not `applicationDidBecomeActive:` is called when `requestAccessToEntityType:` is called. It seems that this behavior (`applicationDidBecomeActive:` being called when `requestAccessToEntityType:` is called) is not specified by Apple, and could change.

Comment: This can more or less be divined from the statement: "the completion handler will be called on an arbitrary queue. Your app is not blocked while the user decides to grant or deny permission." in [the `requestAccessToEntityType:completion:` doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009567-CH1-SW48). The app delegate stuff must be happening on the main queue, and the ordering between queues can't be guaranteed.

Comment: For me it was more less than more more ;).